# Print Matrix error

Tags: c

I've created a program that reads in a 3 rows and 10 columns of floating point numbers from another file. The program is then supposed to print out all 30 values to the screen but instead only the bottom column is printed 10 times.

I am thinking that there must be a problem with my fscanf loop but I am unsure on what it could be.

Main Program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
  FILE *read_tank;
  int linecount = 0;
  float matrix[3][linecount];
  float width, height, depth;
  int i, j;

  read_tank = fopen("tanks.dat", "r");
  if (read_tank != NULL)
  {
    fscanf(read_tank, "%d", &linecount);

    for (i = 0; i < linecount; i++)
    {

    fscanf(read_tank, "%f %f %f", &matrix[i][0], &matrix[i][1], &matrix[i][2]); 
    }
  }
  else
  {
    printf("Open file error\n");
  }

  printf("+------------------------------------------+\n");
  for (i = 0; i < linecount; i++)
  {
    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
      printf("%3f\t", matrix[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  printf("+------------------------------------------+\n");

  fclose(read_tank);
  system("pause");
  return (0);
}
```

File tanks.dat

```
10
2.0 2.0 1.0
3.0 1.5 0.5
2.5 1.0 0.5
1.0 1.0 0.25
0.5 0.25 0.25
5.0 1.2 1.3
2.5 1.1 0.6
0.8 0.8 0.7
0.8 0.7 0.6
0.5 0.3 0.1
```

Comment: `int linecount = 0; float matrix[3][linecount];` allocates no memory for the matrix.

Comment: the variables: depth, width, height are unused.  Suggest compiling with all warnings enabled, then fix those warnings.  (for gcc use '-Wall -Wextra -pedantic')

Comment: this line: 'float matrix[3][linecount];' because linecount is initialized to 0, results in a matrix of 3 lines, of which each line contains no columns! So this line: 'fscanf(read_tank, "%f %f %f", &matrix[i][0], &matrix[i][1], &matrix[i][2]);' is performing undefined behavior by writing outside the bounds of the array.  Such undefined behavior can/will lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: when this line: 'printf("Open file error\n");' is output, the program should exit, NOT start accessing the matrix[][] array as if it contained valid data.

Comment: when calling fscanf() the returned value should always be checked to assure the input/conversion operation was successful.

Comment: when an error occurs, during the handling of that error, the user should be informed of what is known about the error.   rather than using 'printf()' with some generic message,  it is much better to use 'perror()' as that will tell the user exactly what the system thinks is the root cause of the error.

Comment: this nested loop: for (i = 0; i < linecount; i++)
  {
    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
      printf("%3f\t", matrix[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  } is backwards.  the row count needs to be first, not the column count.  Suggest the outer loop be the row count (0...2) and the inner loop be the column count (0...(linecount-1))

Answer (score 1):

I believe your matrix should be defined as below:

```
int linecount = 10;
float matrix[linecount][3];
```

Comment: It is better to move the declaration of `matrix` after the first `fscanf` so that `linecount` gets initialized by that time.

Comment: @Max 
I've tried matrix[linecount][3]; but I get segmentation fault (core dumped) error

Comment: When you debug, what is the value of `linecount` before loop?

Comment: @Jacob , Move `float matrix[linecount][3];` after `fscanf(read_tank, "%d", &linecount);` or simply initialize `linecount` to 10 instead of 0 as shown in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Problems I see:

**Incorrect dimensions used to declare `matrix`**

```
int linecount = 0;
float matrix[3][linecount];
```

These lines are equivalent to:

```
float matrix[3][0];
```

Allowing the user to provide a value of `linecount` later in the code does not change the dimensions of `matrix`.

Your code exhibits undefined behavior since you are accessing `matrix` out of bounds.

You can fix this by

1. Using dynamic memory allocation, or
2. Moving definition of `matrix` after the value of `linecount` has been read.

My recommendation is to go with dynamic memory allocation.

```
int linecount = 0;
float* matrix[3] = {0};
float width, height, depth;
int i, j;

read_tank = fopen("tanks.dat", "r");
if (read_tank != NULL)
{
   fscanf(read_tank, "%d", &linecount);

   for ( i = 0; i < 3; ++i )
   {
      matrix[i] = malloc(linecount*sizeof(*matrix[0]));
   }
```

Remember to deallocate the memory before the program ends by using:

```
   for ( i = 0; i < 3; ++i )
   {
      free(matrix[i]);
   }
```

**Fix the indices used to read data into `matrix`**

Instead of

```
fscanf(read_tank, "%f %f %f",
       &matrix[i][0], &matrix[i][1], &matrix[i][2]);
```

use

```
fscanf(read_tank, "%f %f %f",
       &matrix[0][i], &matrix[1][i], &matrix[2][i]);
           //  ^^^^ 0 and i need to be switched
           //  as do 1 and i, and 2 and i
```

**Fix the indices used to print `matrix`**

Instead of

```
printf("%3f\t", matrix[i][j]);
```

use

```
printf("%3f\t", matrix[j][i]);
                    // ^^^^^ j and i need to be switched
```

Comment: @R Sahu 
I'm sorry but your answer is beyond my current understanding is there a simpler solution?

Comment: @Jacob, you can make it simpler by just using `flloat matrix[3][100];` and making sure that you don't use more than 100 lines. Keep the other changes though.